# UTF-8 encoded to ANSI for Excel in Golang

Tags: go, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-1252

I am currently working on a Go project where I need to generate a CSV file that can be interpreted by Excel using its default encoding configurations. The requirements for the task at hand state that the downloaded file should appear correct in Excel (where the clients actually work with the data). By default, Excel interprets CSV files as ANSI encoded, but Golang uses UTF-8 as its default character encoding. The solution seems pretty simple... We would just need to convert the format, using `golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap package's` Windows1252 encoding, which is equivalent to `ANSI`. However, this did not work as expected.

Here is my `Download` method

```
func Download(invoices []*domainInvoice.ProjectInvoice, sites map[string]*sites.Site) ([]byte, error) {
    data := make([]*ListItemDownload, 0, len(invoices))
    for _, invoice := range invoices {
        data = append(data, newDownloadInvoiceList(invoice, sites[invoice.Invoiced[0].SiteID]))
    }

    csvFile, err := csv.WriteCSVWithComma(data)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    ansi, err := charmap.Windows1252.NewEncoder().Bytes(csvFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return ansi, nil
}
```

It is called after querying the database for a set of records to be downloaded, and the content gets written to csv format using the `csv.WriteCSVWithComma` method - this function just returns a `[]byte` object with csv data.

In my mind, encoding the final result to ANSI should definitely work, but it didn't. Special characters are not handled at all by Excel.

Am I missing something here? Is this a problem purely related with Excel and there is no way to solve it with encodings in the backend?

Comment: What if you create a sample CSV file by hand and populate it with some Windows-1252 data and _verify_ it's indeed encoded as such (and not as UTF-8 or UTF-16), and then open in it Excel? Does it work? (While we're at it, I'd advise against using the term "ANSI" to refer to Windows code pages–you can learn more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page).)

Comment: If Excel looks for a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (I don't know if it does), then prefix the UTF-8 data with the UTF-8 BOM.  `csvfile = append([]byte{0xEF, 0xBB,  0xBF}, csvfile...); return csvfile`

Comment: Excel doesn't assume CSV files to be Windows1252 as far as I can tell from working with CSV:

Comment: Excel does need a UTF-8-encoded BOM to read a UTF-8 file.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I tried adding the BOM to the byte array, and it still produces the same results. I'm not sure if it does need one as well.

Comment: @kostix I created a dummy csv file with special characters in it on purpose to test your hypothesis. I tried saving it with multiple encodings now (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, Windows-1252, ISO). The only one that was able to keep information with it was MacRoman, which I figure is due to the OS I am saving the file with. Now I don't really know whether this will still hold for Windows machines

Comment: "ANSI" in this context is not well-defined. Which actual character set do you need to convert to? Or do you really mean you want it to depend on the user's system settings?

Comment: Look at a hexdump of the CSV and confirm UTF-8 has a BOM (EF BB BF) as the first 3 bytes

Comment: @tripleee From the experiences I have made, it seems that Excel relies on system settings for its default character encoding. You can of course open a file with a custom encoding of your own (in which case the code works). However, I would prefer the import to be performed in the default manner. Anyways, users are all running Windows, while I'm on Mac and can't really confirm which format Excel uses there. I put this question because I tried several encodings that Microsoft states as the default for Windows (e.g., Windows-1252, ISO-8859-1)

Comment: I'm wondering what exactly you did to put a BOM in your UTF-8. In my (limited) experience that should work. (But it's Excel, it's Microsoft; nothing _really_ works and they like it that way.)

Comment: @tripleee I didn't put any BOM initially. From what I gathered in other forums, UTF-8 doesn't really need a BOM (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-with-bom)). I'm really not an expert with character encodings, specially on Windows though, so I might be wrong...

Comment: Indeed a BOM in UTF-8 is a monstrosity, but Windows is too, and basically insists on one.